# This interaction failed: discord-buttons

Tags: node.js, fs, discord-buttons

These buttons don't work as it stands, since it gives me the following error:
[Discord button click error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGAaT.png)

```
const { MessageButton } = require("discord-buttons")
require("discord-buttons")(client);
import * as Discord from 'discord.js';

async function selectCategory(subject: string, message) {

    let exitButton = new MessageButton()
        .setStyle("blurple")
        .setID("exit")
        .setLabel("↩️")
    let backButton = new MessageButton()
        .setStyle("blurple")
        .setID("back")
        .setLabel("")
    let selectButton = new MessageButton()
        .setStyle("blurple")
        .setID("select")
        .setLabel("☑️")
    let nextButton = new MessageButton()
        .setStyle("blurple")
        .setID("next")
        .setLabel("")
    const buttonArray = [exitButton, backButton, selectButton, nextButton];

    let overviewEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed().setColor('0x4286f4').setDescription("Select a Category:")

    let mybuttonsmsg = await message.channel.send({ embed: overviewEmbed, buttons: buttonArray })

    const embedArray = [overviewEmbed]


    let files:string;
    if (subject === ''){
        files = fs.readdirSync('src/answers/Mathematics');
    }else if (subject ===  '⚛️'){
        files = fs.readdirSync('src/answers/Sciences');
    }else if (subject === ''){
        files = fs.readdirSync('src/answers/Geography');
    }else if (subject === ''){
        files = fs.readdirSync('src/answers/English');
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        embedArray.push(new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('0x4286f4')
            .setDescription(files[i].replace('.txt', ''))
        )
    }

    let currentPage: number = 0;

    const collector = mybuttonsmsg.createButtonCollector((button) => button.clicker.user.id === message.author.id, { time: 60e3 });

    collector.on("collect", (b) => {
        b.defer();
        if (b.id == "3") {
            //select
        }
        else if (b.id == "2") {
            if (currentPage !== 0) {
                --currentPage;
                mybuttonsmsg.edit({ embed: embedArray[currentPage], buttons: buttonArray })
            } else {
                currentPage = embedArray.length - 1;
                mybuttonsmsg.edit({ embed: embedArray[currentPage], buttons: buttonArray })
            }
            console.log('back button pressed');
        }
        else if (b.id == "4") {
            if (currentPage < embedArray.length - 1) {
                currentPage++;
                mybuttonsmsg.edit({ embed: embedArray[currentPage], buttons: buttonArray })
            } else {
                currentPage = 0;
                mybuttonsmsg.edit({ embed: embedArray[currentPage], buttons: buttonArray })
            }
        }
        else if (b.id == "1") {
            mybuttonsmsg.delete();
        }
    })
}
```

bear in mind that before anything else I wrote in this function I did spawnSync a python script, which needs to finish running before continuing this program and that this function itself is being called from:

```
client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
    let { name } = reaction.emoji;
    let member = reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id);
    if (reaction.message.id === playID && user.tag !== 'freerice#4898') {
        reaction.message.reactions.removeAll().catch(error => console.error('Failed to clear reactions: ', error));
        
        selectCategory(name, reaction.message);
    }
});
```

Comment: If you are trying to use `messageReactionAdd` to wait for button clicks, you are wrong. You need to use `clickButton` event. (You can also use the `client.ws` `INTERACTION_CREATE` event but it is not recommended as discord-buttons does it for you)

Comment: @MrMythical I'll look into this other event, however, that's actually not where the problem arises. This is because everything before the selectCategory() function call worked, like the removeAll() reactions method. So, how could this relate to my issue?