# Discord.js: wanting to access message from inside another function

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, discord-buttons

This is the main issue that I'm trying to fix (that hasn't been answered so I'm making this more specific question to follow up): [This interaction failed: discord-buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68554039/this-interaction-failed-discord-buttons)

For any other function called from inside this block:

```
client.on('message', msg => {...}
```

I would normally just pass in the msg argument and everything is fine, however, I'm calling function `selectCategory()` from inside of this code block:

```
client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
    let { name } = reaction.emoji;
    let member = reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id);
    if (reaction.message.id === playID && user.tag !== 'freerice#4898') {
        reaction.message.reactions.removeAll().catch(error => console.error('Failed to clear reactions: ', error));
        
        selectCategory(name, reaction.message);    
    }
});
```

So I tried passing in reaction.message to see if it'd have the same use, but I'm pretty sure that this isn't working so I'd like to pass in the original `msg` as an argument in this function call. One possible solution would be to make it a global variable but I couldn't understand how to implement the `window.` object into the first block of code (`client.on('message'){}`)

Here's the `selectCategory()` function as requested by a commenter:

(issue is most likely here when I check to see who clicked on the button when I pass in the reaction.message rather than the original message's author)

```
async function selectCategory(subject: string, message) {
    const write_questions = spawnSync('python', ['src/write_questions.py', subject], { stdio: 'inherit' })

    let exitButton = new MessageButton()
        .setStyle("blurple")
        .setID("exit")
        .setLabel("↩️")
    let backButton = new MessageButton()
        .setStyle("blurple")
        .setID("back")
        .setLabel("")
    let selectButton = new MessageButton()
        .setStyle("blurple")
        .setID("select")
        .setLabel("☑️")
    let nextButton = new MessageButton()
        .setStyle("blurple")
        .setID("next")
        .setLabel("")
    const buttonArray = [exitButton, backButton, selectButton, nextButton];

    let overviewEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed().setColor('0x4286f4').setDescription("Select a Category:")

    let mybuttonsmsg = await message.channel.send({ embed: overviewEmbed, buttons: buttonArray })

    const embedArray = [overviewEmbed]


    let files:string;
    if (subject === ''){
        files = fs.readdirSync('src/answers/Mathematics');
    }else if (subject ===  '⚛️'){
        files = fs.readdirSync('src/answers/Sciences');
    }else if (subject === ''){
        files = fs.readdirSync('src/answers/Geography');
    }else if (subject === ''){
        files = fs.readdirSync('src/answers/English');
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        embedArray.push(new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('0x4286f4')
            .setDescription(files[i].replace('.txt', ''))
        )
    }

    let currentPage: number = 0;
    
    const collector = mybuttonsmsg.createButtonCollector((button) => button.clicker.user.id === message.author.id, { time: 60e3 });

    collector.on("collect", (b) => {
        b.defer();
        if (b.id == "3") {
            //select
        }
        else if (b.id == "2") {
            if (currentPage !== 0) {
                --currentPage;
                mybuttonsmsg.edit({ embed: embedArray[currentPage], buttons: buttonArray })
            } else {
                currentPage = embedArray.length - 1;
                mybuttonsmsg.edit({ embed: embedArray[currentPage], buttons: buttonArray })
            }
            console.log('back button pressed');
        }
        else if (b.id == "4") {
            if (currentPage < embedArray.length - 1) {
                currentPage++;
                mybuttonsmsg.edit({ embed: embedArray[currentPage], buttons: buttonArray })
            } else {
                currentPage = 0;
                mybuttonsmsg.edit({ embed: embedArray[currentPage], buttons: buttonArray })
            }
        }
        else if (b.id == "1") {
            mybuttonsmsg.delete();
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: "but I'm pretty sure that this isn't working..." What evidence do you have that it isn't? Before moving on and complicating the issue, it's best to understand what is going wrong in the first place. Making a global variable just so you can pass an object around is almost never the right solution.

Comment: There is no `window` object in Node.js. If you can pass the `reaction.message` down to `selectCategory` why would you use a global variable? You should also add some minimal code for `selectCategory()` so we can see what your problem is.

Comment: @h0r53 I've just linked the initial problem and included the `selectCategory()` function that works up until `collection.on()` from tests I've already done, hope this helps you help me. @Zsolt Meszaros